# Disable installation permission popup for my installer

Tags: windows-10, installer, digital-signature

I built an application and signed it. The update method of the application is to update silently automatically each time there is a new version.

The problem is, I expected that the **"Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?"** popup will not appear anymore after I bought the signature and used it to sign the installer and every *.exe* from inside. The popup clearly shows **"Verified publisher: [my company]"**, so I don't see the problem.

Is there a possibility to avoid this popup to appear to users when the application updates automatically?

I can't find anywhere if this is possible. The only thing related to this is how a user can disable the notification, but it's a completely another subject.

I am asking this because I think **it's annoying for the user to be asked with each minor update** of the application. Do you think users will simply uninstall the application after many popups?

Comment: This is just how the UAC works. If whatever your updater is performing needs administrative rights, and your application seems to request these, the user will get the alert. Find a way to update without administrative rights and it will be silent.

Comment: Is your target audience the general public, or are you an internal developer working in domain-controlled network? If you're working with general users on their own computers, they, not you, control their UAC settings. If you're working on an internal domain network, you can define trusted sources and trusted installer accounts to run updates silently, basically by telling UAC who to trust beforehand.

Comment: My target audience is the general public. If I understand correctly, there isn't a way to add exceptions in UAC for a public application.